# Java float comparison is not working on RealmObject on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, realm

**[edit]**

This problem only occured due to RealmProxy class not giving correct value in debug mode on Android Studio. Read accepted answer for a good practise.

**[Original question]**

I have `_allowedPercentageDiscount = 0.0` and `perentageDiscount = 1.0`, First I tried with

```
if(_allowedPercentageDiscount < percentageDiscount)
//do something
```

I also tried with

```
 if (Float.floatToIntBits(_allowedPercentageDiscount) < Float.floatToIntBits(percentageDiscount)) {
            //but it never works
        }
```

but it never result true. Then, after some search, I tried with `Float.compare` but it still did not result true. Magically it gives correct result in evaluation window. (Android Studio).

[image]

**What the hell is wrong and what to do?**

//===============
**Edit**

Full Code information requested in comments:
I have a Product class which is:

```
class Product{
     public float _allowedPercentageDiscount, _discountPercentage;

     public float setDiscountPercentage(float percentageDiscount) {
       if (_allowedPercentageDiscount < percentageDiscount) {
           percentageDiscount = _allowedPercentageDiscount;
       } else if (percentageDiscount < 0)
           percentageDiscount = 0;
       return this._discountPercentage = percentageDiscount;
    }
}
```

Now I am calling this method on a list of Products from another class (`Android Fragment`). But condition is not working and discount is set to all products without their `_allowedDiscountLimit`. Stream support for java 6,7 in Android using [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API).

```
private void applyDiscountPercentage(int discountPercentage) {
     Stream.of(cartProducts).forEach(product -> product.setDiscountPercentage(discountPercentage));
}
```

Comment: share your global variable intitialization also. complete code will be helpful

Comment: What type is "_allowedPercentageDiscount"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Keyword is verifiable. You should post enough code that we can run it and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added more code and scenario.

Comment: how you assign value to `_allowedPercentageDiscount`?

Comment: Yes its assigned when product is created and saved. Btw. I did not mention that I am using Realm. So Product is RealmProxy but this is not the problem with integers are anywhere else.

Comment: can be problems with bitwise conversion between signed and unsigned values whatever it was saved to, check what you get in bits in values you are comparing, coz with proper assigning just before compare simple compare with < or > works fine )

Comment: Ok. Guys, sorry. The problem is due to Realm.io. The _allowedDiscountPercentage has value 15 but showing default value 0.0. RealmProxy classes do not carry realm values untill accessed for usage. I found it by assigning this variable to float a, a temporary variable.
Should I remove the question?

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch Your choice; you can always clarify it further and add a nice answer yourself.

Comment: The solution sounds like it derserves an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the code or float but in the way Realm.io classes behave on Android, especially in debug mode related to concept of zero-copy. Any class implementing `RealmModel` or `RealmObject` will not give you correct variable value when you are debugging. Mentioned here [Realm debugging and testing](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#testing-and-debugging).

Hence, in this question case, for example, `_allowedPercentageDiscount` was having value 15 which should have been different for each of the item. the value 15 assigned mistakenly somewhere else in the logic, got me to stuck in the line which need to act on this value.

**Result:**

*You need to take extra care when debugging using Realm classes on Android in calculations and algorithms.* As you can't see realm objects variable values in debugging mode, you can export those classes to normal mode in the time of debugging/development using `Realm.copyFromRealm()`. After success you can use the `RealmResults` for performance and [zero-copy](https://realm.io/news/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/) realm implementation.

Answer (score 0):

write two variable these

```
float _allowedPercentageDiscount=(float) 0.0;  // or 0.0f 
float perentageDiscount = (float) 1.0;         // or 1.0f
if(_allowedPercentageDiscount < perentageDiscount )
```

will return true

but function

```
  Float.compare(f1,f2)
```

this function return 0 if two value the same ,return any integer less than 0 when to f1 less than f2 and return any integer grater than 0 when f1>f2
so in your image return -1 because _allowedPercentageDiscount

description of this function from this link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,%20float)

Comment: Exactly, but it returns 1 and when I evaluate it returns -1. See the image I added in question.

Comment: in your image result is -1-->true answer not 1 because first argument less than second argument according to compare function description